# How to send the push notification in ios

Tags: php, ios, api, rest

I'm developing and news app in ios so,I have prepared the restful service in Php for ios application

Now I have to integrated the push notification features in my application ,I have the developer account of ios.

I have already tried so many of examples but didn't get the results 
All the time I get the error for the ssl failed, so I want to know is the compulsory to have the ssl certifications to that domain from which I'm using for sending the push notification to the ios devices 
Plz share the steps to make this job successful, you suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use some third party service for sending push-notification they provide APIs to integrate with your server side. You can use https://onesignal.com or some similar third party service.

Comment: Thanks for answering imram, my website is in wordpress

Comment: And this is paid service or opensource

Comment: you are developing app in swift or Objective C ?

Comment: @aman I think its free.

Comment: I'm developing in Objective c

Comment: http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Push-Notification-iOS/ links may helps   and make sure your PEM and P12 files make correctly

Comment: Ok thanks @rushi will try this tutorial

Comment: If you can share the error text... it will be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I will share it later on right now I'm not on my desk